# move_iterator is broken for iterators returning prvalues and returns dangling reference

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, move-semantics

I've looked in the STL sources for `std::move_iterator<Iterator>` and found out that it returns `Iterator::value_type&&`. This leads to incorrect behaviour when `Iterator::reference` is an rvalue and not the same as `Iterator::value_type&`.

I have a class with a proxy object as `reference` (like in `std::vector<bool>`), which can implicitly cast to `value_type`. The normal iterator just dereferences to this proxy (the input iterator requirements allow this), but `std::move_iterator` invokes casting to `value_type` with an overhead and then returns a dangling reference to the created temporary object.

`std::move_iterator` still works with `std::vector<bool>` for some reason (probably because bool is a simple type, and a dangling `bool&&` doesn't cause an error), but not with my class. It's confusing me and I don't understand how to fix it, I think it's a bug in STL.

Here is the simplified piece of source for `std::move_iterator` from GCC 4.8.1:

```
template <typename Iterator>
class move_iterator {
public:
    typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
    typedef value_type&& reference;

    reference operator*() const {
        return std::move(*it);
    }

private:
    Iterator it;
};
```

Comment: What category is your iterator? Forward iterators require `reference` to be a `T&` or `T const&`.

Comment: vector<bool> is not a container, so it might have special cases there too

Comment: Then `Iterator::value_type&&` and `std::remove_reference<Iterator::reference>::type&&` are required to be the same type. Note that link isn't standard.

Comment: I'm talking about your iterator not `vector<bool>`. Your iterator is not an InputIterator, and as such the rule above applies.

Comment: @lizarisk: Yes, **input iterators** have different requirements than other iterators and they are slightly more flexible here. But is your iterator type an *input iterator*?

Comment: RA iterators are a refinement of forward iterators. The same rule applies equally.

Comment: I'm not wrong about this. This requirement is specified very clearly in the standard (see David's answer).

Comment: Your iterator is a forward iterator, because it is also a random access iterator. A random access iterator needs to meet the same requirements as a forward iterator.

Comment: *jumps back from comments in David's answer* I don't know what Boost's Random Access Traversal Iterator maps to as `std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category`, but if it's not `std::input_iterator_tag` then `reference` has to be `value_type&`.

Comment: You could make input iterators work with `move_iterator` by storing the `T` inside the iterator rather than the `proxy` returned by `operator*`; then when the `proxy` goes out of scope the object is still alive. Also note that `std::vector<bool>::iterator` is a forward iterator, not just an input iterator.

Comment: What is the definition of your iterator? What is the iterator category detected by the `iteartor_traits`? If your iterator **is** an *input iterator*, then this is a bug in the implementation of gcc, but there is a code smell around an iterator for which `reference` is not a reference to `value_type`

Comment: @Simple `std::vector<bool>::iterator` is *not* a forward iterator: its `reference` type is a proxy object type and not a reference to `bool` per the forward iterator requirements of 24.2.5/1.

Comment: The quoted features of the GCC implementation are explicitly specified in the standard: 24.5.3.1 specifies `value_type` is the `value_type` of the underlying iterator, and that `reference` is `value_type&&`. 24.5.3.3.4/1 states that `operator*` returns `std::move(*current);` (`current` is an exposition-only representation of the current value of the underlying iterator).

Comment: @Casey `std::vector<bool>::iterator` is still a forward iterator as per the requirements in 23.2.1, which the `std::vector<bool>` explicitly refers to.

Comment: @Simple You are mistaken: `std::vector<bool>` is not a container, it fails to meet many of the container requirements. Most notably, `std::vector<bool>::reference` is not "lvalue of `T`" as specified in 23.2.1.

Comment: @Casey I'm aware of `std::vector<bool>::reference` is not an "lvalue of T" but that doesn't mean its iterator is not a forward iterator. [See here](http://ideone.com/9FJzzK) for quick output of GCC. Doesn't prove my point obviously but the standard does say in the specification for `std::vector<bool>` that is iterator is a forward iterator.

Comment: All of this is interesting, but if `Iterator` was an input iterator, wouldn't gcc just do the same thing, and also break things?  Or is there a specialization?

Comment: @Simple I'll repeat that `std::vector<bool>::iterator` does not meet the requirements of a forward iterator as specified in 24.2.5/1, and that's the last I'll say on the topic.

Comment: This is exactly the reason for this proposal to separate element access from traversal: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html

Comment: Anyway, traversal doesn't have anything to do with the bug in `move_iterator`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is known to the C++ committee.  This problem is being tracked by [LWG issue 2106](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2106).  This issue is currently in Open status, meaning the resolution has not yet been decided upon.

### Update

[LWG issue 2106](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2106) was accepted in time for C++17.  The PR is at the bottom of the issue (link corrected in this update).

Comment: Thank you for this comment! The proposed resolution seems to work nicely, why isn't it accepted yet?

Comment: @lizarisk: Because the unpaid volunteers who do this work are overwhelmed with the amount of work that needs to be done (that is in addition to their day jobs).  If LWG 2106 was the only issue they had to deal with, it would be done by now.  I agree with you that the current proposed resolution appears to be correct.  It went through several iterations to get to this point.

Comment: I couldn’t find 2106 in the linked document. Is anyone aware of what was the solution to this issue?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer and corrected the link.